# How can I resize image with PIL on upload and serve them with flask-cloudy?

Tags: python, flask, python-imaging-library

My current solution does't works as expected. I need to get image from `formdata`, resize it and upload to local file server using flask-cloudy. How can I transform `_io.BufferedWriter` back to file object?

And source code:

```
def image_add():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'username' in session:
            file = request.files['image']
            print(file, file=sys.stderr)
            uploadId=str(uuid.uuid4())
            source = storage.upload(file, name=uploadId, extension=["jpeg","jpg","png"], overwrite=False, public=True)
            image_request_result = requests.get(source.full_url)
            image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_request_result.content))
            width, height = image.size
            max_size = [200, 200]
            image_io = io.BytesIO()
            image.save(image_io, format='JPEG')
            with open('%s_%s.jpeg' % (uploadId, '200x200'), 'wb') as file_output:
                print(file_output, file=sys.stderr)
                source0 = storage.upload(file_output, name=uploadId, extension=["jpeg","jpg","png"], overwrite=False, public=True)
                print(source0, file=sys.stderr)
            resp = json.dumps({
                "id": uploadId,
                "url": source.url,
                "full_url": source.full_url
            })
            return Response(resp, status=201, mimetype='application/json')
        else:
            return Response("Not authorized", status=401, mimetype='application/json')
    else:
        return Response("{request.method} is not allowed!", status=400, mimetype='application/json')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I've did it! Hope this answer below would be helpful for someone who uses same libraries and for someone who need to create thumbnails and store it somewhere.

Flask cloudy expects from us to pass ***File*** or ***Path/to/file.string***. The only solution I've found is get requested file, open in with PIL, make smth, save it to bytes, write those bytes to file and pass this file path to Flask Cloudy.

Solution:

```
def image_add():
if request.method == 'POST':
    if 'username' in session:
        file = request.files['image']
        img_sizes = [(128,128),(300,300),(800,600)]
        uploadId=str(uuid.uuid4())
        prefix = uploadId + '/'
        source = storage.upload(file, name=uploadId, prefix=prefix, extension=["jpeg","jpg","png"], overwrite=False, public=True)

        for size in img_sizes:
            image = Image.open(file)
            image_io = io.BytesIO()
            image.thumbnail(size)
            image.save(image_io, 'jpeg')
            thumbName = '%s_%s.jpg' % (uploadId, str('x'.join(tuple(map( str , size )))))
            with open(thumbName, 'wb') as file_output:
                file_output.write(image_io.getvalue())
                file_output.close()
                source0 = storage.upload(thumbName, name=thumbName, prefix=prefix, extension=["jpeg","jpg","png"], overwrite=False, public=True)
                os.remove(thumbName)

        resp = json.dumps({
            "id": uploadId,
            "url": source.url
        })
```